# tag vote count mismatch

Tags: discussion, voting

I am checking my tags and I see vote counts as in the attached image[image]

As clearly visible php has 39 counts for 67 php answers/ question. But as I count the votes for php by search 'user:1699833 [php]' **it is 46**.

I want to know why it is showing 39?